# How to install the latest stable Clang on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, clang

I'm considering switching to Fedora, but the latest stable Fedora (36) only ships Clang 14, while the latest release is Clang 15.

Is there any way to get up-to-date binaries, without switching to the beta version of Fedora?

I found https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/fedora-llvm-team/llvm-snapshots/, but they only produce trunk builds, not the stable releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build the Fedora37 package of clang locally :)

Install `mock`, add your user to the `mock` group, go to the RPM source page, i.e., https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/clang , click on clang-15 for F37, get the   clang-15.0.0-2.fc37.src.rpm , and tell mock to build it in a container for your target architecture (assuming that is x86_64):

```
mock --config /etc/mock/fedora-36-x86_64.cfg --rebuild clang-15.0.0-2.fc37.src.rpm
```

Make yourself a coffee or two, and install the resulting rpms from the target directory you'll see at the very end of a successful run. (Hint: use `cd /path/to/the/binary/rpms; sudo dnf install ./rpm1.rpm ./rpm2.rpm …` to install them, satisfying dependencies as needed. You will need to install clang, libllvm and so on from that directory at once, to let dnf satisfy the dependencies.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to accept this for now, and try it latter, when I muster enough courage to switch.

Comment: The good thing is that this way, as you're building distro-compatible packages, it's trivial to uninstall and install the original version

Comment: The wording of your comment makes it seem you think this method requests a distro update: it does not! This takes the version of clang in fedora 37 and builds it for your current fedora 36, so that you do not have to switch!! That was the whole point.

Comment: Ah, sorry. :) What I mean is, I'll try this when I finally decide to switch to Fedora from a different distro.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Btw, trying distributions in containers is safe and fun ;)

Comment: Though mock is the one thing that won't work in a container, as it will try to nest containers within containers. (You can do the very same without mock, it's just gradually more work)